# Run python script via different server

Tags: python, proxy

I have two servers A and B.

On the server A there are running multiple python scripts.
I want certain operations of those scripts to run from the IP of the server B.
Those operations are using `requests`  and `urllib.request`

I don't want to rewrite the whole application so that it runs on server B.

Is it possible to continue running from server A but for some of the scripts to make the requests via server B? What technologies should I look into using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Celery use case. Celery is a library used to execute Python code on worker through Redis or RabbitMQ, it's pretty useful when you want to execute some function in background.

https://github.com/celery/celery

Does this solution fit with your problem ?

Comment: Probably I didn't describe the problem so well. I want to do http requests (via `requests` and `urllib.request` and get answers directly. As far as I understand using celery would add tasks in a queue and then I would have to check for the result of those tasks, correct? That would not give me an immediate answer.

Comment: Oh sorry yes, I haven't understood well your problem. In my opinion, installing a proxy on the server B and setting requests to use server B as a proxy would works better. In the [documentation of requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) you could pass an array of string as proxy parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the better solution. I have started studying and I am installing a proxy server (squid) on my server B, and then I will investigate how to make it work via python. Thanks, thats it.